# Square Apple Pay Integration: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

Tags: flutter, applepay, square

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'.

when I hit the Apple Pay Button I got this issue.

787406+0530 Runner[6770:338808] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSPlaceholderString initWithFormat:locale:arguments:]: nil argument'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1a718edb4 0x1a56199a0 0x1a653e4bc 0x1a653e380 0x104c1cda0 0x104c13f38 0x104c1e860 0x108ca0b14 0x10878ba8c 0x10511408c 0x1051158c4 0x105124428 0x105124080 0x1a7218ac8 0x1a71fc754 0x1a7200dfc 0x1e10b6984 0x1ae3e3e7c 0x1ae3e3af4 0x102da4d34 0x1c88bede0)

#### Steps to reproduce the issue.

Added latest version of SDK.

1. flutter pubspec.yaml : square_in_app_payments: ^1.7.5
2. initialize Apple Pay
3. call `await InAppPayments.requestApplePayNonce(..)

Here the piece of code that reproduce the issue.

```dart
   InAppPayments.requestApplePayNonce(
      price: "1.0",
      currencyCode: "USD",
      countryCode: 'US',
      summaryLabel: 'Cookie',
      paymentType: ApplePayPaymentType.finalPayment,
      onApplePayComplete: _onApplePayEntryComplete,
      onApplePayNonceRequestSuccess: _onApplePayNonceRequestSuccess,
      onApplePayNonceRequestFailure: _onApplePayNonceRequestFailure,
    );
```

link this question on GitHub :
https://github.com/square/in-app-payments-flutter-plugin/issues/205#issue-1443930410

My app get crashed, I'm running in iPhoneX with iOS 16. please provide the solution as soon as possible.